# Convention for combining GET parameters with AND?

Tags: api-design

I'm designing an API and I want to allow my users to combine a GET parameter with AND operators. What's the best way to do this?

Specifically I have a `group_by` parameter that gets passed to a Mongo backend. I want to allow users to group by multiple variables.

I can think of two ways:

```
?group_by=alpha&group_by=beta
```

or:

```
?group_by=alpha,beta
```

Is either one to be preferred? I've consulted a few API design references but no-one seems to have a view on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no strict preference. The advantage to the first approach is that many frameworks will turn group_by into an array or similar structure for you, whereas in the second approach you need to parse out the values yourself. The second approach is also less verbose, which may be relevant if your query string is particularly large.

You may also want to test with the first approach that the query strings always come into your framework in the order the client sent them. Some frameworks have a bug where that doesn't happen.